# How to rename multiple files at once?

Tags: mac, terminal, macos

I want to rename multiple files at once. For example:

```
Picture1.jpg
Picture2.jpg
Picture3.jpg
Picture4.jpg
```

into

```
Vacation-Picture1.jpg
Vacation-Picture2.jpg
Vacation-Picture3.jpg
Vacation-Picture4.jpg
```

I am quite familiar with the terminal, if there is no app which is quite good in renaming files.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
 for file in Picture*.jpg
 do
    mv "$file" "vacation-$file"
 done
```

(open terminal and add one line {press Enter} at a time.)

What that does is uses the variable file for each entry matching `Picture*.jpg`. Then it takes the file or folder and moves it to be prefixed with "vacation".

Hope that helps

Comment: What if I would like to rename `Vacation-Picture4.jpg` back to `Picture4.jpg`? Namely, removing a word from file name. Thanks!

Comment: @zyy `${file/Vacation-/}` as target (where `${file/find/replace}`)

Answer (score 66):

No need for command line...

1. Add all the images to be renamed into a folder.
2. Select all files, right click mouse and select "Rename *x* items"
3. Select "Add text" from first drop down menu
4. Select "Before name" from the second drop down menu
5. Enter "Vacation_" into the text box (without the quotation marks)
6. Press Enter.

Answer (score 34):

```
brew install rename

rename s/config\./route\.config\./g *
```

First you need homebrew installed. Then install rename, and the above regex renames all files with "config." to "route.config".

So say files config.a.js, and config.b.js -> route.config.a.js, route.config.b.js.

Comment: According to the `brew desc rename` command:
"rename: Perl-powered file rename script with many helpful built-ins". The `brew home rename` command leads to [http://plasmasturm.org/code/rename/](http://plasmasturm.org/code/rename/) for documentation, etc.

Answer (score 6):

After downloading rename

```
brew install rename
```

run following command

```
rename -n -A Vacation- *
```

-A : prepend

-n : Only show how the files would be renamed.

If it looks good, run the same command without -n flags.

Answer (score 5):

While not a Terminal solution, I like [Forklift](http://www.binarynights.com/) for this purpose (and for many others). From their website:

[image: Forklift's Multi-rename feature description]

Comment: Yep, for sure there is a terminal based solution.
I also found this on mighty google ;) http://manytricks.com/namemangler/

Comment: You may as well post NameMangler as an additional answer, since this is basically a recommendation question. :)

Comment: To rename multiple files(recursively) with Forklift .. just select all files then expend all directories by CMD+right .. till you cover them all .. its working with me

Answer (score 5):

I like user933531's answer, but if you'd like a GUI, the [A Better Finder Rename](http://www.publicspace.net/ABetterFinderRename/) app is really good. I got it from the [App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/better-rename-9/id414209656?mt=12).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to bulk rename files I built a small script for that.

```
# Rename Bullk files.
# Renames all the files in PWD with the given extension.
#
# @param extension | jpg
# @param new_name | name
# Usage: rename jpg new_name
function rename() {
    echo "———————————————— STARTED ————————————————"

    # Counter.
    COUNTER=1

    # For do loop.
    for file in *."$1"; do
        mv "$file" "$2-$COUNTER.$1"
        COUNTER=$[$COUNTER +1]
    done
    echo "———————————————— ✔✔✔ RENAMED Every $1 file in the PWD! ✔✔✔︎ ————————————————"
}
```

Just put it in your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` and run `Usage: rename jpg new_name` this will rename all jpg files in the PWD to new_name-1.jpg, new_name-2.jpg, etc.

Cheers!

Comment: Alternatively to put the function in .bashrc or .zshrc files I put it in my .bash_profile and it works great!

Answer (score 0):

try this. do not need run command
https://tidbits.com/2018/06/28/macos-hidden-treasures-batch-rename-items-in-the-finder/

Hope that helps

Comment: Answers should be more than just a link (which may break, rendering your answer useless).