# How to rename multiple files & filepaths at once on Mac without Terminal

Tags: finder, folders, file, macos

Apart from this [topic](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/64497/how-to-rename-multiple-files-at-once) which offers a small variety of code scripts to use on Terminal, I thought using available apps would be more user-friendly.

The Finder in macOS can rename multiple files only if they are under the same directory as described in the "[Rename files, folders, and disks on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/rename-files-folders-and-disks-on-mac-mchlp1144/13.0/mac/13.0)" Apple support webpage but I would like to rename files in different directories. I don't really have the time or the energy to go through deep coding on Terminal to make changes to thousands of files.

So here is my solution in the answer section. Please feel free to comment/add any other simplified solution to rename multiple file (& filepaths) at once on MacOS.

[Other app alternatives](https://www.macgasm.net/software/file-manager-mac/) (haven't tried them yet apart from the one below).

Comment: There is a built in method.  Select the files you want, right click and select “Rename”  A dialog will open with options to select your renaming conventions.

Comment: I am aware of this apple support webpage but it does not allow renaming files in batches that are placed within different foldesr. It basically does not work for multiple folders (you have to search within every folder to rename the files. Also if you have copies elsewhere, you have to search for them individually too).

Comment: There's a reason that shell scripting still exists: because it is much more flexible and configurable that any app, where the interface has to cater to each possible option. However, it might help if you could provide some examples of the type of change and the scope (e.g.  recursively through the hierarchy from some point, or just "all files"). The chances are that this could be done with one line in the Terminal.

Comment: To remove a monstruous number of files, all you need is `find` with the `-exec` option. No GUI will ever be as efficient and versatile as such a simple command. Moreover, it's an easy case to start gaining in skill.

Answer (score -1):

I'm currently using [Transnomino](https://www.transnomino.com/) (hard to find decent functional ones) and this is how I used the app to rename filenames and filepaths :

1. Open the app
2. Select Full Path (in this example) & set the replace criteria to `Regular Expression`
   [image: Transnomino main window]
3. Click on the `+` button on the right then, in the **Find:** entry, double-click on `One or more entry`
   [image: Transnomino Find field]
4. Set the **Count** to **1** (for 1 occurrence). Then add specific characters you need to remove from file name and filepath in `Custom Characters`, in this example : **~!@#$%^&*()_+?[:"<>|]**
   [image: Transnomino enter characters]
5. Return to main app window and fill in the **Replace:** field with what you would like to replace the specific characters mentioned above with (*if you need to replace them with nothing, just leave it blank*)
   [image: Transnomino replace field]
6. Open your Finder folder and drag the folders/files you want to apply this to
   [image: Transnomino files drag]
7. Note the files that are grayed and the others: when it's gray, the app doesn't need to change anything (= none of the specific characters are present in filename or filepath). All the others CAN be renamed.
   [image: Transnomino rename summary]
8. If you're satisfied with it, just click `Rename`. *Et voilà*
   [image: Transnomino renaming complete]

Comment: Transnomino is no longer maintained. The repo is gone and the homepage is down.

Comment: Does this still exist?