# Renaming multiple files with mv gives "zsh: no matches found: *.pdf"

Tags: command-line, zsh

So I have these files:

```
 Movies % ls -l *."pdf - yts"
-rw-r--r--@ 1   staff  1848890 Mar 18 00:11 Scanned Document 1.pdf - abc
-rw-r--r--@ 1   staff  1848890 Mar 18 00:11 Scanned Document 2.pdf - abc
-rw-r--r--@ 1   staff  1848890 Mar 18 00:11 Scanned Document 3.pdf - abc
-rw-r--r--@ 1   staff  1848890 Mar 18 00:11 Scanned Document 4.pdf - abc
 Movies %
```

and I need to rename the extensions from `.pdf - abc` to just `.pdf`.

I tried this:

```
mv *."pdf - yts" "*.pdf"
```

but got this error:

```
zsh: no matches found: *.pdf
```

Is there a one-liner that I can use here?  Or is my command not formatted correctly?

Comment: Something doesn't quite add up: your `ls -l *."pdf - yts"` doesn't match the `- abc` suffixes you show on the files.

Comment: And the error message just says `*.pdf` -- it doesn't mention `- yts`

Comment: Since you are trying to move several files in one command, `zmv` would be a suitable.  See _man zshcontrib_ and serarch for `zmv` to see, how this is used. Note that you have to do an `autoload zmv` first, to make this command available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mv -h` (help) shows the usage of mv:

> ```
> usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-hv] source target
>        mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory
> ```

This shows `mv` takes one source and target, or one or more sources and a target directory.

If your command were to succeed, it would be equivalent to

`mv Scanned Document 1."pdf - yts" Scanned Document 2."pdf - yts" Scanned Document 3."pdf - yts" Scanned Document 4."pdf - yts" "*.pdf"`

This is trying to move the 4 documents to the directory `"*.pdf"`, which does not exist, hence the error.

---

To rename multiple files to multiple targets, you can use a `for` loop.

```
for file in *."pdf - abc"; do mv "$file" "${file/ - abc/}"; done
```

- `for file in *."pdf - abc"; do …; done` runs `…` with `$file` variable set to each file resulting from the glob `*."pdf - abc"`.
- `${file/ - abc/}` finds  `- abc` in the `$file` and replaces it with , removing it.

---

You also [don't need to use the command line for this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/239259/37797).

Comment: The error message is coming from zsh, not mv.

Comment: Why was this answer accepted? It has nothing to do with the error message.

Comment: @Barmar I didn’t say the error message was produced by mv, but rather that mv was being used incorrectly.

Comment: That's true, but fixing that won't solve the problem because it's happening in the shell before `mv` runs. This answer is only useful after they solve the wildcard problem.

Answer (score 6):

This solution uses `zsh`'s `zmv`-

Navigate to the directory where these files exist and load `zmv`.

```
autoload zmv
```

Test the results of `zmv` by using the `-n` option.

```
zmv -n '(*).pdf - abc' '$1.pdf'
```

Remove the `-n` option if the results are what you desire.

Comment: `zmv -Wn '*.pdf - abc' '*.pdf'` also works well for patterns like this.

Answer (score 5):

There is a utility called `rename` that you can install that will do just this.

```
rename "pdf - abc" "pdf" *."pdf - abc"
```

If it isn't on your system, you can install it with `brew install rename`.  There are some packages where rename is called `rename.ul`

Note that your comments used the string "yts", but your example listing has "abc" in it.

Comment: On Ventura at least, `rename` is not a standard macOS included CLI tool, nor is `rename.ul`, so your qualification of 'most systems' doesn't hold true here. You need to update your answer to point the OP and other readers at a source of the executable, such as from brew (e.g. `brew install rename`). Note, it is a Perl  script, so other infrastructure would be prerequisite, but brew would handle that.

Comment: @AndyGriffiths - thanks for the comments, I updated my answer to show where to get package.  I've had it on my system for a long time and forgot it wasn't standard.

Comment: Ty... note that `rename.ul` seems to be specific to Debian systems and derivatives such as Ubuntu, specifically it indicates it comes from the `util-linux` package. So it is unlikely to be encountered in the macOS universe. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/444524/7952

Comment: I think your suggestion  of using `rename` is a great answer  and as a side note `brew` is not a standard macOS included CLI tool. It's a third party package manager.